# How to read subset of columns in Polars DataFrame when `has_header=False`?

Tags: python-polars

I am working with a Polars DataFrame. When I read the DataFrame with `has_header=True`, it fails to correctly identify the column names. When I read it as follows, everything works smoothly, and the column names specified in `dtypes` are appropriately defined, which is the desired outcome:

```
vcf = pl.read_csv(
    vcf_path,
    comment_prefix='#',
    has_header=False,
    separator='\t',
    dtypes=dtype_options,
)
```

Now, the challenge arises when I aim to read only subsets of `columns`. I attempted the following:

```
vcf = pl.read_csv(
    vcf_path,
    comment_prefix='#',
    has_header=False,
    separator='\t',
    columns=list_of_columns,
    dtypes=dtype_options,
)
```

However, this results in the error: `"ValueError: specified column names do not start with 'column_', but autogenerated header names were requested."`

I understand that this error occurs because `has_header=False`, and the column names are not defined until the last reading step. Any assistance on how to resolve this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you read the data with `pl.read_csv` and `has_headers=False` what are the column names? All the columns should be named `column_*`, but it sounds like that is not the case? Can you provide a sample csv file to test the behaviour?

Comment: It sounds like your data has headers, but you set `has_headers=False` to prevent polars from reading the names wrong. Usually, then the column names are then in the first row of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use scan instead.

Assuming your `dtype_options` is a dict of the columns you want and their dtype such as `{'column_1':pl.String, 'column_3':pl.Float64}`

then you'd do

```
vcf = pl.scan_csv(
    vcf_path,
    comment_prefix='#',
    has_header=False,
    separator='\t',
    skip_rows=1 # or however many for the header 
).select(
    pl.col(f"column_{x}").cast(y) for x,y in dtype_options.items()
).collect()
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer works in most cases but fails for compressed csv.